# Visual Studio 2017 bug

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-2017

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3tQH.png)

Sometimes when I change my tabs I get weird blank page.
I already tried to change my theme to dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS environment options you can uncheck **Use hardware graphics acceleration if available**, in case your problem is caused by a faulty video card driver:

[image]